# Add key bindings to control specific context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, menuitem, attachedbehaviors

I'm unable to get the keyboard shortcuts working on context menu items belonging to specific controls and I was wondering if anyone could help me.

Use case: I'm trying to write an attached behavior that can be applied to various elements in order to provide undo/redo context menu functionalists to those controls. The context menu part is working but the key bindings don't seem to work.

What I've tried so far:

**Attempt 1:**

```
var menu = new ContextMenu();
var undoCommand = new DelegateCommand(Undo);
var undoMenuItem = new MenuItem
{
     Header = "Undo",
     Command = undoCommand,
     InputGestureText = "Ctrl+Z",
};

menu.Items.Add(undoMenuItem);
AssociatedObject.ContextMenu = menu; // AssociatedObject is a textbox as an example
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
var menu = new ContextMenu();
var undoCommand = new DelegateCommand(Undo);
var undoMenuItem = new MenuItem
{
    Header = "Undo",
    Command = undoCommand,
};

undoMenuItem.InputBindings.Add(new InputBinding(undoCommand, 
    new KeyGesture(Key.Z, ModifierKeys.Control)))

menu.Items.Add(undoMenuItem);
AssociatedObject.ContextMenu = menu; // AssociatedObject is a textbox as an example
```

Neither of these seem to be working. The context menu is selectible from the UI (right click on a text box for instance and select "Undo") but the keyboard shortcut is not fired.

Is there a way to do this in an attached behavior? I would like to avoid having access to the underlying `Window` element inside my attached behavior if possible and would like the keys to work within their respective bounds (for instance, only if the text box is focused should `Ctrl+Z` cause an Undo on that text box).

Many thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get the undo "button" in the context menu to do what Ctrl-Z does or are you trying to handle the input Ctrl-Z when the context menu is open?

Comment: I would also suggest creating the context menu in xaml rather than in the code-behind as that is best practice especially since you aren't dynamically generating the menu options at runtime (even then writing in xaml is still probably preferable, but binding gets tricky)

Comment: @user2455627 I'm trying to get the Ctrl+Z to execute a custom command (in this case, UndoCommand) when user presses the button combination and the text field is focused. I can't do it in XML since this is part of an attached behavior.

Comment: You are binding the InputBinding to the MenuItem, your command will only fire when the undo MenuItem is focused, and then you press ctrl-z. You want the InputBinding bound to the textbox, or whatever control you want the undo to effect, since that is what will presumably be focused when you press ctrl-z